# Windows 10 Sleep fails from Start menu, but not from idle

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

My Windows 10 machine has recently (last couple of weeks) started having problems sleeping.

If the machine is left idle with no sleep-blocking software, like games, running, it will go to sleep after the configured power-management timeout. It will wake on keyboard, and the Windows state has been correctly remembered.

However, if I choose "Sleep" from the Power menu in the Start menu, the sleep doesn't work properly. It sounds like the fan and hard-drive noise stops too soon. There's then about a 50% chance it will stay powered off and doesn't respond to keyboard - if powered on with the power button, Windows has lost its running state and boots as fresh.

Alternatively, after sleeping the system may power itself back on but doesn't boot (and the keyboard's Numlock indicator doesn't light). It needs to be restarted, and Windows has lost its running state.

This started a little while after, but not immediately after, I changed the motherboard and CPU.

Any idea what's going on?

**Edit**: This question is now moot, as the computer completely stopped booting in the last few days. PSU is the main suspect, but all the voltages test OK. There's no speaker in the case, so I can't get POST diags; I have a speaker on order.

Comment: Of course, having posted this, it's just idle-slept and failed too.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade the BIOS and Power Driver both. Restart, reset sleep settings and test.

Comment: I confess, I'm unclear what the Power Driver is (I'm familiar with upgrading the BIOS, and with device drivers etc. I just haven't heard of the Power Driver)

Comment: If it is a desktop machine there may not be a separate power driver

Comment: How old is it? I have recently also problems with sleeping, and the doctor said it's age related... ;-)

Comment: I was thinking more it must be to do with 2020...